# Where is the `display` command in Big Sur

Tags: terminal, applescript, notifications

I'm trying to send a notification to notification center. I'm able to use:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Basic Text Here" with title "Title Text Here"'
```

There's notes floating around the web that says there's a stand alone `display` command, but it doesn't appear to be on my machine. (I had a display command that was from ImageMagik which I uninstalled but it was under `/usr/local` so I wouldn't expect it to be the problem.)

Does the `display` command still exist in Big Sur? If not, is there an alternative?

Comment: The **AppleScript** _command_ in your question, run with `osascript`, works for me in **macOS Big Sur** 11.4 without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

There's not and never has been a `display` binary.
It begins the AppleScript command `display notification`.